# Pandas create dataframe column by assigning a value to matching records

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe and I want to assign a value to a nonexisting column by setting the value to records that match a criteria. This is my attempt:

```
criteria = ["XX", "XY", "XYY"]
dataframe.loc[dataframe["criteria_column"].isin(criteria)]["new_column"] = 1000

dataframe["new_column"]
```

The problem is that this code is raising the following error:

```
KeyError: 'new_column'
```

I tried the code with a dataframe whose all records match the criteria, and got the same error.

Comment: I think you're close. Try `df.loc[df["criteria_column"].isin(criteria), "new_column"] = 1000` instead.

Comment: Initialize the column first to a default value.df["new_column"]=0

Comment: @Asettisriharsha There's no need. `.loc` will create the column when used this way and fill the rest with `NaN`~

Comment: @BeRT2me Why don't you answer the question? your solution works

Answer (score 1):

try with

```py
df.loc[df['criteria_column'].isin(criteria),"new_colum"]= 1000
```

Comment: *If* you can elaborate on *why* this works, and *why* OPs answer doesn't, I'll gladly support your answer.